# Facebook Open Graph publish to page wall with mention tagging

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Does facebook allow Open Graph publishing posts to a page's wall?

I haven't found the documentation on FB where it states that you can't publish to a page's wall using Open Graph.

I can use the app's access_token to publish to a user's wall but I get "(#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories" message when I try that with page's wall. Even tried with the page's access_token.

Is this just not possible?